# Eloquent. Cast select's as integer within relationship?

Tags: php, eloquent

i'm trying to create a re-useable method which can get the minimum and maximum values from a table, but for any column I ask for.

So for example below I want to min and max of `price`. However this value is being returned as a string:

```php
$result = [
    "price" => [
        "min" => "2200.00",
        "max" => "45340.00"
    ]
];
```

I want to return this, and avoid additional manipulation of the data:

```php
$result = [
    "price" => [
        "min" => 2200,
        "max" => 45340
    ]
];
```

This is my current method.

```php
public function vehiclesMinMax($column)
{
    return $this->hasOne(Vehicle::class)
        ->selectRaw(new Expression("MIN({$column}) AS min, MAX({$column}) AS max"))
        ->where($column, '>', 0)
        ->first();
}
```

What I tried to do is use `withCasts`, however this doesn't appear to be available for `database/Query/Builder.php`

```php
public function vehiclesMinMax($column)
{
    return $this->hasOne(Vehicle::class)
        ->selectRaw(new Expression("MIN({$column}) AS min, MAX({$column}) AS max"))
        ->withCasts([
            'min' => 'integer',
        ])
        ->where($column, '>', 0)
        ->first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do this another way, just added the the result to a collection so I can use `map`. Arrow functions on available `7.4+`.

```php
public function vehiclesMinMax($column)
{
    return collect($this->hasOne(Vehicle::class)
        ->selectRaw(new Expression("MIN({$column}) AS min, MAX({$column}) AS max"))
        ->where($column, '>', 0)
        ->first())
        ->map(fn($item) => (int) $item);
}
```